# Is there a gcloud command to disable all previous versions of a secret?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-secret-manager

I am looking for a `gcloud` command to disable all the previous secret versions except the latest one.

Let me explain my entire use case:

So, I've a bitbucket pipeline which creates a new version every time I run this pipeline. I am using the following command to add a new version to already existing secret:

```
gcloud secrets versions add api-server-versions --data-file=./new.json
```

Now, this command creates a new version of secret every time the pipeline is ran. Leaving previous versions are still enabled.

So, what I want to do is disable all the previous versions of secret as soon as the new secret version is created.

Is there any `gcloud` command to achieve this or any other way to do this using commands?

Comment: There is not. You would need to list the secrets and then call disable on each.

Comment: Yeah, @sethvargo when I was researching I concluded that too. But I thought if there's any work around using `|` or `filter` that might help. Though, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Posting this as a community wiki, since it's based on the discussion between @Sethvargo's and the OP in the comments to the question:

Unfortunately there is no way to do this with a single command nor by using `|` or `filter` in the gcloud command so what you have to do in order to achieve this is to list the secrets and disable each one individually.

All that being said, this might be considered a good feature on a gcloud command, so if you'd like, you can [create a feature request](https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers#:%7E:text=Create%20new%20Cloud%20SDK%20issue) so this is considered to be implemented by the Google Cloud team in the future.

Answer (score 0):

In order to disable secret version it requires secret admin role on the project or organization and Iam roles cannot be granted on secret versions
refer this [link](https://cloud.google.com/secret-manager/docs/managing-secret-versions#disable) for more details.

another way is you can disable previous versions and add new versions by using [command](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/secrets/versions/disable)